# Restrict function call to page load but not ajax call

Tags: admin, ajax

I use the following to stop Subscribers (and Customers) from accessing the admin area of my site:

```
/**
 * Redirect back to homepage and not allow access to WP admin for Subscribers.
 */
function xcsn_redirect_from_admin(){
    if ( ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_posts' ) ) && ( ! is_checkout() ) ){
        wp_redirect( site_url() );
        exit;
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'xcsn_redirect_from_admin' );
```

It works great except that it interferes with an ajax call that my checkout page is making (WooCommerce). The call stalls and the checkout can't proceed unless you have 'edit-posts' privileges, which defeats the purpose, obviously.

**My question:** is it possible to set a conditional that will work with an early call like `admin_init` that will allow the ajax calls to get through but *won't allow* the admin backend to be loaded as a page?

(Sorry if the title is unclear - it was hard to fit into a single sentence!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the constant `DOING_AJAX`. It is always defined when someone uses the WordPress AJAX API.

```
if ( defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) && DOING_AJAX )
    return;

if ( is_admin() )
    add_action( 'admin_init', 'xcsn_redirect_from_admin' );
```